# Reaquiring Curator InterProcessReadWriteLock

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am trying to replace database pessimistic lock with Curator interprocess lock. With a database lock, I take a `select for update` lock on an entity at the beginning of a transaction and it is released when the transaction is committed. The transaction could span over multiple methods and if any method in the chain tries to acquire this lock again, it gets it as it is running in the same transaction/thread.

Now with zookeeper lock, the examples that I've seen look like this:

```
InterProcessMutex lock = new InterProcessMutex(client, lockPath);
if ( lock.acquire(maxWait, waitUnit) ) 
{
    try 
    {
        // do some work inside of the critical section here
    }
    finally
    {
        lock.release();
    }
}
```

This would create a problem if I service call spans over multiple methods and any of those methods individually tries to acquire this lock. I don't want the lock to be passed around as these are independent business methods. Could there be some service/factory implementation which could return this same lock object if I am running in same thread?

Comment: what about to put it to threadLocal?

Comment: That can be done, but I was wondering if there exists some standard way of fetching this lock?